# Does someone know why \titleformat with in article environment does not work?

Tags: titles

I am trying to use the command `\titleformat` but it is not working. Does anyone what my mistake could be?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sf,sl,outermarks,noindentafter,nobottomtitles]{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}[hang]{\LARGE\bfseries}

\title{h}
\author{gh}
\date{February 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `[hang]` is causing the error (at least for me)

Comment: Anyway, ‘hang’ is the default.

Answer (score 3):

The package options do not all seem to work, but this code does. Note that `hang` is the default, so you don't  have to use it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sf,sl,outermarks,noindentafter,nobottomtitles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries\itshape}

\title{Fiddle-dee-dee!}
\author{Tweedledee \& Tweedledum}
\date{February 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @cgnieder: Thanks for the edit! Once more, I forgot to check if everything was OK  :–(